# An alternative query to postgres' distinct in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Given this django model:

```
def Price(model.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The goal is to get the most recent price for each item which can be queried quite simply.. assuming the orm is using postgresql:

```
Price.objects.all().order_by('date').distinct('item')
```

When using other database engines, it isn't possible to `distinct on` specific fields, and I'd like to avoid locking myself into postgres so I've been looking for a query that emulates it. I've written/found a query that does the job:

```
Price.objects.raw('''
    SELECT P1.*
    FROM `merchapi_pricelog` P1
        LEFT JOIN `merchapi_pricelog` P2
            ON P1.item_id = P2.item_id AND P1.date < P2.date
    WHERE P2.date is NULL
''')
```

The raw query is faster than loading and filtering the data in code but I am interested to see if there is a better way to do this in a db-agnostic way that doesn't resort to using raw sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could annotate it in with a subquery, so it's accessible inside an Item queryset. It's a little vice-versa, as it seems you want a Price queryset containing this data, but this could still work for you:

```
latest_price = Price.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('id')).order_by('-date').values('price')[:1]
items = Item.objects.annotate(latest_price=Subquery(latest_price))
```

I didn't test that code, just borrowed and modified from something similar I had in another project, but believe it's accurate.

If you need to be iterating through a Price queryset, rather than an Item queryset...my brain can't think of anything at the moment :)

Comment: It doesn't matter what "side" it's coming from in this case so this is a good solution.

Comment: OK, excellent! I made a quick edit as you only need the first value from the subquery